# How to create Facelets subpage

Tags: jsf, facelets

Say I have a file `index.xhtml`, how can I dynamically create subpages for it like `index.xhtml?id=1`. And is there any way to grab this `id=1` with some actions in this page?

Comment: @JeffNoel a suggestion that can't be applied isn't a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

That's why [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) tag exists in JSF. It allows you to get the query parameter(s): those after `?` and separated with `&`, and use it in your view directly, or set it as a model property, convert/validate it, etc.

But you're getting its meaning the wrong way. It is not used to create 'many (sub)pages', but to *pass information to the view*, so that view could be dynamic, meaning that rendered information will be derived basing on those view parameters (i.e. showing user with a certain id). It also thus allows to create bookmarkable URLs.

Its usage is basically as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{yourBean.userId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This will preset the given property of your bean with the parameter passed to the view as query parameter.

You can find more information in answer to [What can `<f:metadata>` and `<f:viewParam>` be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377957/1820286).